# Why Spring program doesn't show images in freemarker template?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I created a simple Spring web app that must save images and show it on screen, but my app can't find image in system. Saving was realized without problems, but app can't find images in my file system => can't show it on browser page.

*Images saved in upload path without problem*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NIk6.png

**My WeBMvcConfigurer**

```
@Configuration
public class WebMVC implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Value("${upload.path}")
    private String uploadPath;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:/" + uploadPath + "/");
    }
}
```

**Freemarker template that must show images with title and tag**

```
<#if posts??>
<#list posts as post>
    <div class="card text-white bg-secondary my-3">
        <img src="/img/${post.imageName}" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">${post.title}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">${post.tag}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</#list>
</#if>
```

The template was supposed to display a image, but for some reason can not find them.

**Full project**
https://github.com/Vakarine/ImageBank.git

Comment: When you get the page, and you look at the page source downloaded to the browser, are the image src URLs correct? In your Spring code, `upload.path` is a variable and here it looks like it should just be `/img/`?

Comment: @CharlesForsythe Yes, the src of images were correct. I found the source of the problem - I needed to add `(" / ")` in @GetMapping in MainController